# how do i change the time interval of the bumblebee status bar in i3

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, window-managers, i3

the status bar configured with bumblebee refreshes every 6seconds in my case

`https://bumblebee-status.readthedocs.io/en/main/features.html`

This doc page suggests a technique to change the interval of particular modules but when I follow the doc it refreshes every 6+1second instead of refreshing every 1 second.
This causes the seconds part in the time module to refresh every 6 seconds
This is the link for the bumblebee installation

`https://github.com/tobi-wan-kenobi/bumblebee-status/archive/refs/tags/v2.1.6.zip`

I'm expecting a solution for refreshing my status bar every 1 second because seconds part of the time module refreshes every 6 seconds.

Comment: While you may be able to get answers here, this question may be better suited on [the discussion forum](https://github.com/tobi-wan-kenobi/bumblebee-status/discussions) of the bumblebee-status project itself, where its developers and users are.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.